# VS Code cannot find GOROOT when VS Code connects to a remote server

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I setup go run environment on a Debian 9 remote Linux machine and can run GO code without problem. Then I tried to connect to the remote machine using VS Code. It was successful but VS code complained it could not find GOROOT. I've setup the envs in the .bashrc. Where can I specify these Environment Variables in VS Code? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can specify the GOROOT in `settings.json` as below:

[image]